# Is there a program similar the Universal Copy app for Linux?

Tags: linux, clipboard

I would like to copy a text in any program on Linux as I usually do on Android using [Universal Copy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.camel.corp.universalcopy),
but currently I didn't get any results searching about on Linux

[image]

Comment: your question belongs at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: why do you require an app ... doesn't ctrl-c work for you?

Comment: It's for copying text that can't be copied into a program window with a tab or something like that, even if using

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.